# Google Sheets - Finding the most recent date based on a value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-macros, google-sheets-formula

I have a table showing the name of everyone who has received feedback and when they received the feedback, however, some people received feedback on multiple dates so I need a formula to find the most recent date and copy it across to a seperate sheet.

I have attached the google sheets below. For example, the second tab shows the name of each person in the table but I need to know the most recent date they received feedback based on the data from sheet 1.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1n3c6F97-10mzZ8g3VYroRgl5ullXz_dDJrpdV5SQRLg/edit#gid=1526292532

Any help is most appreciated

Comment: could you please post the screenshot of the sample data? That will serve as my reference

Answer (score 2):

Use the following formula

```
=maxifs(B:B,A:A,F2)
```

where f2 contains the name of the person you need the information. I've also edited your sheet. Note that i had to rewrite some of your dates, as they were being recognized by sheets as text, not dates.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to create a list names

```
=UNIQUE(A1:A29)
```

Then as Oren just posted, this will give you the highest date, but you may need to fix your data formatting for it work.

```
=maxifs(B:B, A:A, D2)
```